# How can I fix the streaking on the side of this cube in Blender 2.83?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

I recently used Blender 2.83 to create a textured cube. I first made a UV map, and then applied a texture. I also scaled the texture using the Texture Coordinate, and Mapping modules in the Material Nodes. I then got the wanted result, but only on the top and bottom face. Here is my result: [image]

Is there a possible way, to get my wanted result, and also fix the streaking?

Comment: Don use object or generated coordinates you need UVs. To understand texture coordinates i suggest you watch the following video [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=263)

Comment: I'll check it out.

Comment: @susu I am not sure, if that is what I am looking for. Could you explain more, why I should look at it?

Comment: to understand how texture coordinates work.

Comment: It is just an unwrapping issue.I suggest to unwrap that face separately or smart UV project the entire cube

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though either: 1. you are not using the UVmap you created, 2. there a different materials applied to different faces, or 3. The object is not unwrapped correctly.

First, make sure that in your node setup you have the UV output on the Texture Coordinate node connected to vector input socket on Mapping node.

Second, make sure that all your faces have the same material assigned. Select all of your faces in edit mode and in the materials tab, choose the correct material and click assign.

Third, try unwrapping again. Go into edit mode. select all of your faces. choose UV Unwrap.

Comment: What about the *seems*?

Comment: I am certian I am using it, it is the same material, and I am sure the uv map is correct. I think I might just unwrap that face sepperately